# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8983 Error in the IndexWorker logs in Sitecore xConnect

Tags: xconnect

I am running Sitecore 9.update1 with Solr 6.6.2 and I am seeing lot of error in the IndexWorker logs in Sitecore xConnect as below

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it **127.0.0.1:8983**
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost.d__28.MoveNext()

Solr is running correctly at https://localhost:8983/solr/, but when called from IndexWorker, the error described above will appear.

For any advice, thank you JS

Comment: is it secured the connection to solr, do you have a valid certificate?

Comment: is your setting ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress set to https://localhost:8983/solr ?

Comment: Hi Anton,
yes i have correctly set ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress to [https://localhost:8983/solr](https://localhost:8983/solr)

Comment: Hi Vlad, SSL is set correctly because when I open the solr through the browser at [https://localhost:8983/solr](https://localhost:8983/solr) everything is ok.

Comment: 1. Is the certificate trusted? You can check that if you open Chrome and check if it says "Secure" in the address bar.
2. Is "solrCore" connection string in xConnect IndexWorker pointing to localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Did you try to stop the solr on 8983 using cmd and then start it again? We faced a similar issue and solved it by stopping solr forcibly from command prompt and start it again. Make sure to restart your xConnect services.